# running async JS functions on BigQuery with #standardSQL

Tags: javascript, sql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, webassembly

Now that BigQuery supports async on #standardSQL, how can I convert this #legacySQL function to run on #standardSQL?

```
#legacySQL
SELECT SUM(s)
FROM
js((
  SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*100000) group, NEST(requests) as x
  FROM (
    SELECT requests, content_size
    FROM [fh-bigquery:wikipedia.pagecounts_201205]
  )
  GROUP BY group)
  , group, x
  , "[{name:'s', type: 'float'}]",
"function (row, emit) {
  const memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 256, maximum: 256 });
  const env = {
      'abortStackOverflow': _ => { throw new Error('overflow'); },
      'table': new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 0, maximum: 0, element: 'anyfunc' }),
      'tableBase': 0,
      'memory': memory,
      'memoryBase': 1024,
      'STACKTOP': 0,
      'STACK_MAX': memory.buffer.byteLength,
  };
  const imports = { env };
  const bytes = new Uint8Array([0, 97, 115, 109, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 139, 128, 128, 128, 0, 2, 96, 1, 127, 0, 96, 2, 127, 127, 1, 127, 2, 254, 128, 128, 128, 0, 7, 3, 101, 110, 118, 8, 83, 84, 65, 67, 75, 84, 79, 80, 3, 127, 0, 3, 101, 110, 118, 9, 83, 84, 65, 67, 75, 95, 77, 65, 88, 3, 127, 0, 3, 101, 110, 118, 18, 97, 98, 111, 114, 116, 83, 116, 97, 99, 107, 79, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119, 0, 0, 3, 101, 110, 118, 6, 109, 101, 109, 111, 114, 121, 2, 1, 128, 2, 128, 2, 3, 101, 110, 118, 5, 116, 97, 98, 108, 101, 1, 112, 1, 0, 0, 3, 101, 110, 118, 10, 109, 101, 109, 111, 114, 121, 66, 97, 115, 101, 3, 127, 0, 3, 101, 110, 118, 9, 116, 97, 98, 108, 101, 66, 97, 115, 101, 3, 127, 0, 3, 130, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 1, 6, 147, 128, 128, 128, 0, 3, 127, 1, 35, 0, 11, 127, 1, 35, 1, 11, 125, 1, 67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 7, 136, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 4, 95, 115, 117, 109, 0, 1, 9, 129, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 10, 196, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 190, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 7, 127, 2, 64, 35, 4, 33, 8, 35, 4, 65, 16, 106, 36, 4, 35, 4, 35, 5, 78, 4, 64, 65, 16, 16, 0, 11, 32, 0, 33, 2, 32, 1, 33, 3, 32, 2, 33, 4, 32, 3, 33, 5, 32, 4, 32, 5, 106, 33, 6, 32, 8, 36, 4, 32, 6, 15, 0, 11, 0, 11]);
WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, imports).then(wa => {
      const exports = wa.instance.exports;
      const sum = exports._sum;
      for (var i = 0, len = row.x.length; i < len; i++) {
        emit({s: sum(row.x[i], row.x[i])});
      }
  });
}"
)
```

(from https://medium.com/@hoffa/bigquery-beyond-sql-and-js-running-c-and-rust-code-at-scale-33021763ee1f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you can create an `async function x()` and then return `x()`.

Instead of being able to `emit()` multiple times, you'll have to nest the results into array.

Working example:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION `magic_function`(x ARRAY<INT64>) RETURNS ARRAY<INT64> LANGUAGE js AS '''
const memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 256, maximum: 256 });

const env = {
    'abortStackOverflow': _ => { throw new Error('overflow'); },
    'table': new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 0, maximum: 0, element: 'anyfunc' }),
    'tableBase': 0,
    'memory': memory,
    'memoryBase': 1024,
    'STACKTOP': 0,
    'STACK_MAX': memory.buffer.byteLength,
};

const imports = { env };

const bytes = new Uint8Array([0, 97, 115, 109, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 139, 128, 128, 128, 0, 2, 96, 1, 127, 0, 96, 2, 127, 127, 1, 127, 2, 254, 128, 128, 128, 0, 7, 3, 101, 110, 118, 8, 83, 84, 65, 67, 75, 84, 79, 80, 3, 127, 0, 3, 101, 110, 118, 9, 83, 84, 65, 67, 75, 95, 77, 65, 88, 3, 127, 0, 3, 101, 110, 118, 18, 97, 98, 111, 114, 116, 83, 116, 97, 99, 107, 79, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119, 0, 0, 3, 101, 110, 118, 6, 109, 101, 109, 111, 114, 121, 2, 1, 128, 2, 128, 2, 3, 101, 110, 118, 5, 116, 97, 98, 108, 101, 1, 112, 1, 0, 0, 3, 101, 110, 118, 10, 109, 101, 109, 111, 114, 121, 66, 97, 115, 101, 3, 127, 0, 3, 101, 110, 118, 9, 116, 97, 98, 108, 101, 66, 97, 115, 101, 3, 127, 0, 3, 130, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 1, 6, 147, 128, 128, 128, 0, 3, 127, 1, 35, 0, 11, 127, 1, 35, 1, 11, 125, 1, 67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 7, 136, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 4, 95, 115, 117, 109, 0, 1, 9, 129, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 10, 196, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 190, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 7, 127, 2, 64, 35, 4, 33, 8, 35, 4, 65, 16, 106, 36, 4, 35, 4, 35, 5, 78, 4, 64, 65, 16, 16, 0, 11, 32, 0, 33, 2, 32, 1, 33, 3, 32, 2, 33, 4, 32, 3, 33, 5, 32, 4, 32, 5, 106, 33, 6, 32, 8, 36, 4, 32, 6, 15, 0, 11, 0, 11]);

async function main() {
  const wa = await WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, imports);
  const exports = wa.instance.exports;
  const magic_sum = exports._sum;
  return x.map((val) => {
    return magic_sum(val, val);
  });
}

return main();

''';

SELECT SUM(s) sum_s
FROM (
  SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*100000) grp, magic_function(ARRAY_AGG(views)) s
  FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` 
  WHERE DATE(datehour) = '2019-01-01' AND wiki='pt'
  GROUP BY grp
), UNNEST(s) s
```

(https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138430827#comment9)
(h/t https://twitter.com/mylesborins)

Comment: Is there any simpler way to load a wasm file into a user defined function on bigquery?

Comment: Yes, would you like to ask a new question? (for space reasons)

Comment: Sure, I will dot that, also I have the question of why TextEncoder is not included in the Bigqeury UDF environment? I seem to need that to conveniently passing String values between Rust code and Javascript code.

Comment: I have asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60094731/can-i-use-textencoder-in-bigquery-js-udf
And here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60094498/for-bigquery-js-udf-is-there-any-simpler-way-to-load-a-wasm-file-into-a-user-de

Comment: Also, does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430104/bigquery-javascript-udf-process-per-row-or-per-processing-node/59430591#59430591 mean that the grouping operation are outdated and not really needed in the above answer to speed things up? :)

Comment: I would like to use Golang for that purpose. The only examples I see related to Golang is with main(). I would like to create same function add(x) and use it is wbeassebly in BigQuery.