# BigQuery JavaScript UDF process - per row or per processing node?

Tags: performance, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I'm thinking of using BigQuery's JavaScript UDF as a critical component in a new data architecture. It would be used to logically process each row loaded into the main table, and also to process each row during periodical and ad-hoc aggregation queries.

Using an SQL UDF for the same purpose seems to be unfeasible because each row represents a complex object, and implementing the business logic in SQL, including things such as parsing complex text fields, gets ugly very fast.

I just read the following in the [Optimizing query computation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute) documentation page:

> **Best practice**: Avoid using JavaScript user-defined functions. Use native UDFs instead.
>
> Calling a JavaScript UDF requires the instantiation of a subprocess.
> Spinning up this process and running the UDF directly impacts query
> performance. If possible, use a native (SQL) UDF instead.

I understand why a new process for each processing node is needed, and I know that JS tends to be deployed in a single-thread-per-process manner (even though v8 does support multithreading these days). But it's not clear to me if once a JS runtime process is up, it can be expected to get reused between calls to the same function (e.g. for processing different rows on the same processing node). The amount of reuse will probably significantly affect the cost. My table is not that large (tens to hundreds of millions of rows), but still I need to have a better understanding here.

I could not find any authoritative source on this. Has anybody done any analysis of the actual impact of using a JavaScript UDF on each processed row, in terms of execution time and cost?

Comment: If ad-hoc aggregation queries can express their logic in SQL and all the data (that forms a row) can be selected using SQL only, then parsing complex text fields can be done using JS as a post-processing step. This approach is demonstrated by this [project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery). I'm the author. For example, this [function](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery/search?q=clipString&unscoped_q=clipString) replaces the trailing part of long strings with triple dot. You can obviously apply more complex logic and do those things on the backend, not on the client or on both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not documented, then that's an implementation detail that could change. But let's test it:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION randomThis(views INT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  if (typeof variable === 'undefined') {
     variable = Math.random()
  }
  return variable
""";

SELECT randomThis(views), COUNT(*) c
FROM (
  SELECT views
  FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` 
  LIMIT 10000000
)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

[image]

I was expecting ten million different numbers, or a handful, but I only got one: The same process was reused ten million times, and variables were kept around in between calls.

This even happened when I went up to 100 million, signaling that parallelism is bounded by one JS VM.

Again, these are implementation details that could change. But while it stays that way, you can make the best use out of it.

Comment: Commented in another answer below

Answer (score 0):

> I was expecting ten million different numbers, or a handful, but I only got one

That's because you didn't allow `Math.random` to be called more than once

> and variables were kept around in between calls

due to the variable defined at the global scope.

In other words your code explicitly permits `Math.random` to be executed once only (by implictly defining the variable at the global scope).

If you try this:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION randomThis(seed INT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  let ret = undefined
  if (ret === undefined) {
     ret = Math.random()
  }
  return ret
""";

SELECT randomThis(size), COUNT(*) c
FROM (
  SELECT repository_size as size
  FROM `my-internal-dataset.sample-github-table` 
  LIMIT 10000000
)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

then you get many rows. And now it does take much longer time to execute, probably  because the single VM became a bottleneck.

Used another dataset to reduce the query cost.

Conclusion:
1. There is one VM (or maybe a container) per query to support JS UDF. This is in line with a single subprocess ("Calling a JavaScript UDF requires the instantiation of a subprocess") mentioned in the documentation.
2. If you can apply execute-once pattern (using some kind of a cache or coding technique like memoisation) and write a UDF similar to the previous answer, then the sheer presence of JS UDF has a limited impact on your query.
3. If you have to write a JS UDF like in this answer, then the impact on your query becomes very significant with query execution time skyrocketing even for simple JS code. So for this case it's certainly better to stay out.

Comment: `In other words your code explicitly permits Math.random to be executed once only (by implictly defining the variable at the global scope)` - that's exactly what I wanted to test - if the behavior would act globally (single reused VM), or if many VMs would participate in the call

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Taking into account one-to-one relationship between JavaScript UDF and the subprocess which the UDF causes to be instantiated (doco says _"Calling a JavaScript UDF requires the instantiation of a subprocess"_ making it clear there are no multiple subprocesses) it would be reasonable to assume a single subprocess means a single VM. But I agree it's good to have it confirmed by extra testing.