# For BigQuery JS UDF, is there any simpler way to load a wasm file into a user defined function on?

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

As illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57897905/running-async-js-functions-on-bigquery-with-standardsql/), dumping the wasm byte code and copy past into the javascript seems difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you mean a better way than copying into JS - I haven't investigated that (yet), but this will make UDFs easier for others to use:

- Move the .js out of the query into a file.
- Create a persistent function.

Then people will be able to call it like this:

```sql
SELECT fhoffa.x.sample_wasm_udf([2,3,4])
```

To create this function I did:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fhoffa.x.sample_wasm_udf(x ARRAY<INT64>) 
RETURNS ARRAY<INT64>
LANGUAGE js AS '''
   return main(x)
'''
OPTIONS (library="gs://fh-bigquery/js/wasm.udf.js");
```

For more on persistent functions, see:

- https://medium.com/@hoffa/new-in-bigquery-persistent-udfs-c9ea4100fd83

Comment: Aha, I see, thanks, this could help I think. Just a follow up question, only gs:// is supported? If the js file is on some github page or on some web server, would it be also supported?

Comment: @Felipe is there a place where I can see all global persistent UDFs available? Like "fhoffa.x...."?