# Can I use `TextEncoder` in Bigquery JS UDF?

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I am trying to use some Rust wasm code in Bigquery as UDF, and in order to pass on Java String to Rust code the `TextEncoder` and `TextDecoder` would be needed to conveniently doing that. As it mentioned here [Passing a JavaScript string to a Rust function compiled to WebAssembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014610/passing-a-javascript-string-to-a-rust-function-compiled-to-webassembly)

But when I try out some of my code on BigQuery, I encountered an error saying `TextEncoder` is not defined.

[image]

You can try it out as well with a query like this:
https://github.com/liufuyang/rb62-wasm/blob/master/try-3-old.sql

While a working version without using `TextEncoder` is at https://github.com/liufuyang/rb62-wasm/blob/master/try-3.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means the object is not defined.

As an option, bring your own TextEncoder.

For example, take your `try-3-old.sql`, and then add this line at the end of the JS UDF definition:

```sql
return main();
'''
OPTIONS (library="gs://fh-bigquery/js/inexorabletash.encoding.js");
```

And now it works:

[image]

---

(wondering, what's the goal with rb62?)

Comment: Thank you, I think this is exactly what I need.

Comment: About the goal with rb62: basically it is used internally at Spotify to encode/decode some gid (128bit or 16byte) to 62 based value, as in those examples show. We already have a js UDF library to do this. I am just testing out 1. whether it is possible to use some Rust/wasm function to do the same via js UDF interface. 2. Could the speed be improved or not as we normally have millions of rows to parse.

Comment: What I find so far is that, as it is not convenient to pass JS string (utf16) values to the wasm Rust code environment (where the string is in utf8, also this seems can only be done via copy stuff through the wasm memory), it seems not gaining any performance benefit, specificly when trying to replace some JS string encoding lib to a Rust string encoding lib?

Comment: Please accept answer if useful! And let's start a new question to find a way to improve performance as desired :)

Comment: Thank you. I will try out some stuff then ask if necessary :)

Comment: Cool! I think the problem with performance in this case is the initialization of wasm, but I have some ideas on how to improve that problem.

Comment: I have tired the idea of grouping stuff to avoid too much wasm init as you showed in some other answers and blog post. But it still runs slower than a pure JS function. You can see a query example here 
https://github.com/liufuyang/rb62-wasm/blob/master/try4.sql

I was told by Pauna that :"because even though Rust strings are faster than JS strings, it has to do a full copy when converting from a JS string to a Rust string or a Rust string to a JS string so that negates the performance benefits"

I think that is probably the case for me.